# How to make a C++/CLI ref class to data member of WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, c++-cli

I'm trying to convert my c# application to WCF service.

In c# application, there's some c++/CLI class.

I need to send that class as a return value to the client via WCF.

Can I use a [DataContract] for c++/CLI ref class?

Here's sample code

```
// This is C++/CLI Class
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace CLIClass
{   
    class TestClass
    {
    public:
        int index;
        int test;
    };
}
```

.

```
//This is WCF service code.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    TestClass GetData(int index);   // I need to return "TestClass"
}

//    
[DataContract]
/* How can I make a Data Contract? */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `[DataContract]` attribute just like any other attribute.

In your case, the problem comes from the fact that you didn't declare a `ref class` (managed class), but a `class` (native class). Just use `ref class` and you'll be able to write:

```
namespace CLIClass
{  
    [System::Runtime::Serialization::DataContract]
    ref class TestClass
    {
    public:
        [System::Runtime::Serialization::DataMember] property int index;
        [System::Runtime::Serialization::DataMember] property int test;
    };
}
```

(and avoid `using namespace` in header files)

You need to add a reference to the System.Runtime.Serialization assembly, you can do that through the project properties, or by adding the following line:

```
#using <System.Runtime.Serialization.dll>
```